# How best to write this xtext grammar

Tags: grammar, xtext, bnf, context-sensitive-grammar

I am using Xtext, and need suggestions on the following two problems.

**Problem #1**

Lets say I have three rules a, b and c. And I want to allow any sequence of these rules, except that b and c should appear only once. How best to write such a grammar?

Here is what I came up with:

```
root:
  a+=a*
  b=b
  a+=a*
  c=c
  a+=a*
;
a: 'a';
b: 'b';
c: 'c';
```

Is there a better way to write root grammar? b and c still have to be in a strict order, which is not ideal.

**Problem #2**

Have a look at this grammar:

```
root:
    any+=any*
    x=x
    any+=any*
;

any:
    name=ID
    '{'
        any+=any*
    '}'
;

x:
    name='x' '{' y=y '}'
;

y:
    name='y' '{' z=z '}'
;

z:
    name='z' '{' any+=any* '}'
;
```

Using this grammar I expected to be able to write a language like below:

```
a {
    b {

    }

    c {
        y {

        }
    }
}

x {
    y {
        z {
            the_end {}
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an error due to the node "y" appearing under "c".  Why is that? Is it because now that "y" has been used as a terminal in one of the rules, it cannot appear anywhere else in the grammar?

How to fix this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem #1:

```
root: a+=a* (b=b a+=a* & c=c a+=a*);
```

For problem #2 you need a [datatype rule](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#datatype-rules) like this:

```
IdOrABC: ID | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' ;
```

and you have to use it in your `any` rule like `name=IdOrABC` instead of `name=ID`.

Comment: Yes I thought of that too after posting my answer, but didn't pursue it further and instead opted to use vaildators. It seemed like a better choice. I will, however, accept your answer because it does seem right, even though I would not be able to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

For problem #1, we can adjust the grammar like below:

```
root:
  a+=a*
  (
    b=b a+=a* c=c
    |
    c=c a+=a* b=b
  )
  a+=a*
;
a: 'a';
b: 'b';
c: 'c';
```

On the other hand, the problem #2 cannot really be solved via the grammar as parser can never differentiate between an ID and the special keyword "x", "y" or "z". Perhaps a better strategy would be to keep the grammar simple like below:
    root:
      any+=any+
    ;

```
any:
  name=ID
  '{'
    any+=any+
  '}'
;
```

And enforce the special x/y/z hierarchy via validators.

Comment: For problem 1, your solution is feasible because you have only 2 unordered "special cases" ``b`` and ``c``, which result in 2 possible orderings ``... b ... c ...`` and ``... c ... b ...``.

But if you have ``n`` special cases, you have ``n!`` possible orderings, which makes the grammar huge. So even for 3 or 4 special cases, you will need a different solution, based on unordered groups.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how this can be done through unordered groups?